# Display array of text in annotationView using index

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I can't display all the addresses in my variable

```
var allAddress: [Address] = []
```

In this **variable** i get from **firebase** a small amount of addresses and i want to display all addresses in my **annotationView**, but when i try to display all addresses i see only one address in all **annotationView** though if i make printed my using for..in.. **index** i see **index0**, **index1**, **index2**, **index3** and other... as well if i printed this:

```
print("address - \(allAddress[index].address)")
```

i get all address which i have in **firebase**, their total **6**.

It's print my **index** and **allAddress[index].address**

```
index 1
address - Москва, ул. Правды д.24, строение 3
index 2
address - Москва, ул.Электрозаводская д.21
index 3
address - Москва, ул.Бутырская д.8
index 4
address - Москва, 2-Я Звенигородская улица 12 строение 21
index 5
address - Москва, Николоямская 52, стр. 1
```

It's my code:

```
let centerInfo = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100))
    for index in 0..<allAddress.count {
        print("index \(index)")
        centerInfo.text = allAddress[index].address
        centerInfo.numberOfLines = 0
        centerInfo.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

        print("address - \(allAddress[index].address)")
    }
    annotationView?.detailCalloutAccessoryView = centerInfo
```

How i can display all addresses in my `centerInfo.text`?

And pls check .gif which shows the same address on all annotationView

[image]

P.S. in annotation.title don't need to use, me do not fit

**UPDATED**. All code:

```
class AllAddressMapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

var allAddress: [Address] = []

var studioRef: DatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    studioRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Photo1")

    studioRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        for imageSnap in snapshot.children {

            let studioObj = Studio(snapshot: imageSnap as! DataSnapshot)

            self.allAddress.append(studioObj)

            for index in 0..<self.allAddress.count {

                let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

                geocoder.geocodeAddressString(self.allAddress[index].address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in

                    guard error == nil else { return }

                    guard let placemarks = placemarks else { return }

                    if let placemark = placemarks.first {

                        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

                        guard let address = placemark.location else { return }
                        annotation.coordinate = address.coordinate

                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

                    }

                    geocoder.cancelGeocode()

                })

            }

        }

    })

    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.mapType = .standard
    mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
    mapView.isScrollEnabled = true

}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }

    let annotationID = "PinMap"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationID) as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationID)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    let leftImageNavigationButton = UIImage(named: "auto")
    let tintedColorleftImageNavigationButton = leftImageNavigationButton?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let leftNavigationButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    leftNavigationButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    leftNavigationButton.setImage(tintedColorleftImageNavigationButton, for: UIControlState())
    leftNavigationButton.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftNavigationButton

    let rightButtonInfo = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButtonInfo

    let centerInfo = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100))
    for index in 0..<allAddress.count {
        print("index \(index)")
        centerInfo.text = allAddress[index].address
        centerInfo.numberOfLines = 0
        centerInfo.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

        print("address - \(allAddress[index].address)")
    }
    annotationView?.detailCalloutAccessoryView = centerInfo

    annotationView?.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -8, y: 0) 

    return annotationView

}
```

}

Comment: Completely normal! You're setting the same **centerInfo.text** each time you looped. Then, the final *centerInfo.text* (which is displayed) is, in fact, the last address in your array. Try to send an array of UILabel instead of only one and manage correctly it into the concerned viewController.

Comment: Oh, how me to display all addresses in `centerInfo.text` from `print("address - \(allAddress[index].address)")?`

Comment: Could you please post your code ? A snippet of code like you did is not enough :-)

Comment: Try `centerInfo.text = (centerInfo.text)! + allAddress[index].address`

Comment: @KosukeOgawa `centerInfo.text = (centerInfo.text)! + allAddress[index].address`
Got a nil :(

Comment: @AntoineRucquoy posted all code

Comment: Sorry, How about this? `centerInfo.text = (centerInfo.text ?? "") + allAddress[index].address`

Comment: @KosukeOgawa it worked, but now I have on each annotationView all addresses, in first annotationView i have 6 addresses, in second annotationView i have 6 addresses and so on :)

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks , you are using same `UILabel` for all annotation and in loop you are setting the `text` property of the same `UILabel` every time. That's why it's showing the last `address` on all annotation.

Try to assign a separate `UILabel` for each annotation and set `text` property to the designated `address`

Comment: It's very hard, because in future i will be display 500+ addresses, I on the other can not do it?

Comment: Then what you can do is, assign address to centerInfo only when you popover a particular annotation at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the idea is to get all annotations on your map like that and try to find the right annotation index to reuse it into your allAddress array :

```
var indexValue = 0
    for annotationInMap in mapView.annotations {

        if annotation == annotationInMap {
           let centerInfo = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100))

            centerInfo.text = allAddress[indexValue].address
            centerInfo.numberOfLines = 0
            centerInfo.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

            annotationView?.detailCalloutAccessoryView = centerInfo
        }


        indexValue = indexValue + 1
    }
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, it is probably due to the "**if annotation == annotationInMap**" condition. You need to find something that you sure that the annotation is related to the right index in your array. To avoid an error like "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" (Out of bounds exception).

Comment: Yes, it's doesn't work :( I don't know yet how to fix it, I will think how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

How about setting address to `annotation.title` in viewDidLoad, and get `annotation.title` in viewFor method.

```
class AllAddressMapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var allAddress: [Address] = []

    var studioRef: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        studioRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Photo1")

        studioRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            for imageSnap in snapshot.children {

                let studioObj = Studio(snapshot: imageSnap as! DataSnapshot)

                self.allAddress.append(studioObj)

                for index in 0..<self.allAddress.count {

                    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

                    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(self.allAddress[index].address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in

                        guard error == nil else { return }

                        guard let placemarks = placemarks else { return }

                        if let placemark = placemarks.first {

                            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

                            guard let address = placemark.location else { return }
                            annotation.coordinate = address.coordinate
                            annotation.title = self.allAddress[index].address

                            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

                        }

                        geocoder.cancelGeocode()

                    })

                }

            }

        })

        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.mapType = .standard
        mapView.isZoomEnabled = true
        mapView.isScrollEnabled = true

    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }

        let annotationID = "PinMap"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationID) as? MKPinAnnotationView

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationID)
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        } else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        let leftImageNavigationButton = UIImage(named: "auto")
        let tintedColorleftImageNavigationButton = leftImageNavigationButton?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let leftNavigationButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        leftNavigationButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        leftNavigationButton.setImage(tintedColorleftImageNavigationButton, for: UIControlState())
        leftNavigationButton.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftNavigationButton

        let rightButtonInfo = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButtonInfo

        let centerInfo = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 100))
        for index in 0..<allAddress.count {
            print("index \(index)")
            centerInfo.text = annotation.title
            centerInfo.numberOfLines = 0
            centerInfo.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

            print("address - \(allAddress[index].address)")
        }
        annotationView?.detailCalloutAccessoryView = centerInfo

        annotationView?.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -8, y: 0)

        return annotationView

}
```

Comment: Good idea, it's working, but i get duplicate address and see two address, at the first address not have .byWordWrapping, at the second have .byWordWrapping

Comment: actually I realized the problem is how to make .byWordWrapping in annotation.title